# vmware fusion cannot connect to network

Tags: networking, vpn, vmware-fusion

If I don't believe wrongly. I think VMware fusion use Cisco Any connect to connect to internet right? However, now the Cisco in my windows virtual machine reports:

VPN service not available

The VPN agent service is not responding. Please restart this application in a few minutes.

And thus my virtual machine cannot connect to this network, where as my mac connects perfectly fine. Any one knows what is happening ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I think VMware fusion use Cisco Any connect to connect to internet right?

Wrong. They use your MAc to connect to the network.